# Understanding variable mistakes within closures?

Tags: javascript, function, closures

I am learning about closures. This example is given as a common mistake made when making a closure:

```
function assignTorpedo(name, passengerArray) {
    var torpedoAssignment;
    for (var i = 0; i<passengerArray.length; i++) {
        if (passengerArray[i] == name) {
            torpedoAssignment = function() {
                alert("Ahoy, " + name + "!\n" +
                "Man your post at Torpedo #" + (i+1) + "!");
            };
        }
    }
    return torpedoAssignment;
}
```

Since the for loop completes before the closure is returned, the i value will not match with the name. So, I understand that the loop continues on before the return happens.

My question comes from this, an example of the correct way to do things:

```
function makeTorpedoAssigner(passengerArray) {
    return function (name) {
        for (var i = 0; i<passengerArray.length; i++) {
            if (passengerArray[i] == name) {
                alert("Ahoy, " + name + "!\n" +
                "Man your post at Torpedo #" + (i+1) + "!");
            }
        }
    };
}
```

I don't understand why in the above example the for loop wouldn't also continue past the first time it finds a match, which would result in another mismatched i. I understand that return stops a function, but I don't understand the connection between the return and that first match since they don't happen together (visually). I understand how the code knew to stop if that return was within the if function or the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't understand why in the above example the for loop wouldn't also continue past the first time it finds a match

It would.

> which would result in another mismatched i.

It wouldn’t, because it checks `if (passengerArray[i] == name)` every time. That’s wasteful, though; it’s an unusual fix. A better way would be to pass the index:

```
function makeTorpedoAssigner(passengerArray, i) {
    return function (name) {
        alert("Ahoy, " + name + "!\n" +
              "Man your post at Torpedo #" + (i+1) + "!");
    };
}

function assignTorpedo(name, passengerArray) {
    for (var i = 0; i<passengerArray.length; i++) {
        if (passengerArray[i] == name) {
            return makeTorpedoAssigner(passengerArray, i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "it checks ... everytime". (Apologies if this is frustrating). If the loop continues past the matching i, incrementing every loop, wouldn't the i end up as a greater value than the value that matches the name, just like in the erroneous example? My rudimentary understanding is that, to avoid the error in the first example, the code has to know when to stop, aka return, but if the return isn't bound to the condition that satisfies, and the loop does continue, how does it know the correct i to use?

Comment: @user4853: When the function returned by `makeTorpedoAssigner` is called, it loops through `passengerArray` itself and calls `alert("Ahoy, " + name + "!\n" + "Man your post at Torpedo #" + (i+1) + "!");` immediately. That’s why it has the right `i`: the actions involving `i` have already completed by the time `i` is incremented.

Answer (score 0):

What happens here is :

> assignTorpedo() returns a function based on name, So, every time it
>   checks for name in passengerArray and returns a function, but before
>   assignTorpedo could return torpedoAssignment, value of i would have
>   changed to the last value (length-1 of passengerArray), as loop will continue executing.

```
function assignTorpedo(name, passengerArray) {
    var torpedoAssignment;
    for (var i = 0; i<passengerArray.length; i++) {
        if (passengerArray[i] == name) {
            torpedoAssignment = function() {
                alert("Ahoy, " + name + "!\n" +
                "Man your post at Torpedo #" + (i+1) + "!");
                // value of i
            };
        }
    }
    // value of i = length of Array since loop has executed fully
    return torpedoAssignment;
}
```

Right approach explained :

> Here you are returning a function which takes a name and checks each
>   time in the array, the concept of closure here is that, even though
>   function(name) is returned, it would remember passengerArray (if you
>   will see passengerArray is not passed everytime, but no error is
>   thrown. This is closure.)

```
function makeTorpedoAssigner(passengerArray) {
    return function (name) {
        for (var i = 0; i<passengerArray.length; i++) {
            if (passengerArray[i] == name) {
                alert("Ahoy, " + name + "!\n" +
                "Man your post at Torpedo #" + (i+1) + "!");
                //value of i
            }
        }
    };
}
```